# Cant get glossy material in Unity?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, baking, unity

Ok, so trying everything I can here but seeing as I cant get exporters like B2U to work, I am relying on Unity's shaders and other answers on here trying to achieve this glossy material (see the white shine) from Blender to Unity:

[image]

Right now Ive applied diffuse, specular, and standard shaders in Unity, all just look like this -

[image]

No shine, very flat. Is this a lighting problem? Or how can I preserve Blender's glossy look in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Specular map for best results, a Reflection Probe also. Substance Painter is a fast and easy way to create these maps for Unity. [image]